# HTMLDocument, HTMLEditorKit, and blank spaces

Tags: java, dom, htmleditorkit

When I run the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.EditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
    .
    .
    .
        String content = "x";
        String html = "<html><body><dyn/>" + content + "<dyn/></body></html>";
        final Reader reader = new StringReader(html);
        final EditorKit editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();

        HTMLDocument hTMLDocument = new HTMLDocument();
        editorKit.read(reader, hTMLDocument, 0);
        Element defaultRootElement = hTMLDocument.getDefaultRootElement();
        Element branchElement = defaultRootElement.getElement(1).getElement(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < branchElement.getElementCount(); i++) {
            Element element = branchElement.getElement(i);
            System.out.print(element);
        }
```

I get the following output:

```
LeafElement(dyn) 1,2
LeafElement(content) 2,3
LeafElement(dyn) 3,4
LeafElement(content) 4,5
```

However, if I change the value of `content` to `" "`:

```
    String content = " ";
```

I get this output:

```
LeafElement(dyn) 1,2
LeafElement(dyn) 2,3
LeafElement(content) 3,4
```

Why is a content `LeafElement` constructed for `"x"`, but not for `" "`?  I want a `LeafElement` to be constructed for `" "`.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with `HTMLDocument` or `HTMLEditorKit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **I'm hoping for an explanation of why this is happening.**

This is just the product of whitespace collapse in HTML. Since that space you're inserting is the only thing between the two `<dyn/>` tags, it gets ignored by the parser, thus not being represented by a LeafElement.

- **Possible solution**

As camickr mentioned, you would have to use non-breaking space entities to preserve all whitespaces. But, since you have no control over the HTML, your best bet is to customise HTMLEditorKit's parser. Perhaps the following resources may come in useful:

- [HTMLEditorKit and Custom tags in the JEditorPane/JTextPane.](http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html)
- [Parsing HTML files with HTMLEditorKit.](http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/parsing_html_files_with_htmleditorkit)
- [Parsing HTML with Swing.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31059)
- [The HTML Editor Kit](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/goodies/HtmlEdKit.pdf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Paul-Reiners Hey! Thanks a lot for accepting the answer after so long.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about the editor kit but maybe you can use `&nbsp;` instead of " ".

Comment: I've thought about that.  The HTML is coming from elsewhere (and is much more complex than what I'm showing).  We would have to insert the "&nbsp;" characters, which is certainly possible, if it comes to that.  But I'm hoping for an explanation of why this is happening.